# div not expanding to percentage on all monitor sizes

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a

```
container:100%
contentcontainer:90%
```

and then inside these I have

```
#bookinfo{width:75%; float:left;}
sidebar{width:20%; float:right;}
```

The `#bookinfo` div contains books with these styles

```
display inline 
width:320px
height:430px
float:left
margin right:15px
```

I thought setting `bookinfo` to a width of 75 percent would make it responsive to all monitor sizes, but on one monitor I get three books snug to the sidebar and the other monitor I get three books with a large gape between the books and the sidebar. When using firebug, I saw the 75% was not reaching the sidebar on the larger monitor as it was on the smaller monitor.

I've tried setting the `bookinfo` div to a pixel value, but it still does not render the same on all monitors. I just want as many books to fit as the monitor will allow. So what am I doing wrong?

***SOLVED***

I was able to get the same look on all monitors by removing the `contentcontainer` entirely, setting `container` to `max-width:90%` and removing the width from `#bookinfo` in favor of adding `padding-right`. This worked. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: create a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Jdze/16/

Comment: The sidebar is actually level with the books on my site and the books come from a database so the html is only shown once for .books in the actual code, not three times like the fiddle.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code that goes against displaying "as many books to fit as the monitor will allow". Could you be more specific with the problem? Also, what does "level" mean in your previous comment?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The width of #bookinfo is set to 75 percent of #contentcontainer. Given this, shouldn't the 75% span same in all monitors? In a larger monitor, 75% does not go all the way to the left side of the sidebar, which it should. If it did, another movie would fit.

Comment: If you solved it, the best course is to put your solution in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to add

```
html, body{width:100%; height:100%}
```